# APEX Modal Page Plugin doesn't allow more then one submit/edit without refresh

Tags: javascript, oracle, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I am using the SkillBuilders Modal Page Plug-in for my Oracle APEX application, and everything works, except if I submit anything on the modal page, I can't use any of my buttons on the original page anymore...so say I have a button that says ,request form', and it opens a modal page and I fill out the form, and I click submit, it auto-closes (using the plugin) and if I were to try to click the 'request form' button again, it doesn't let me.

I have this problem in other places as I use a a link column in another table to edit entries in a table, and if I 'apply changes', and then want to click on another link column, it won't allow me to. Instead, I have to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I just found the answer here: http://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/skillbuilders-modal-page-instructions/

"Make sure to select Dynamic in the event scope, or else the column link won’t work after the modal page is closed, and you have to reload the page."

Comment: This pertains to any report with partial page refresh. Any event handlers need to be reinstantiated 'after refresh' of the region, in the case of dynamic actions - it's setting that attribute to Dynamic.